# Are there any downsides to submitting POST data as a JSON object vs. individual fields?

Tags: php, forms, post

Are there any downsides or pros/cons for submitting POST data as a JSON object vs. individual fields? Or is this completely inconsequential and entirely up to preference? For example, say you have a form with the fields `name`, `age`, `likes`, where `likes` is essentially an array.

1. POST data contains JSON object to be parsed:

   ```
   data {
       name: "John Calvin",
       age: 40,
       likes: [
           "Theology",
           "France",
           "Polemics"
       ]
   }

   // Server side
   $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
   // ... process data
   ```
2. POST data contains typical fields:

   ```
   name=John Calvin
   age=40
   likes[]=Theology
   likes[]=France
   likes[]=Polemics

   // Server side
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   ...
   $x = $_POST['x'];
   // ... process data
   ```

Comment: This appears to be referring to PHP? The specifics on, say, performance could differ between which server-side language/framework you are using. Also, please focus your question on a single, objectively-answerable question. As it is written, this appears to be asking for opinions, which is generally off-topic.

Comment: I'll limit it to PHP. Whether or not there are downsides or pros or cons isn't fact but opinion?

Comment: "preferred standards", and "If you have the freedom to choose, which way should you go" sure do seem to be inviting opinion.

Comment: I added those after the fact. My title specifically asks for downsides.

Comment: If you leave in the opinion-soliciting phrases, the question will likely get closed. I'll leave it up to you if you want to edit your question.

Comment: Edited. I'm asking to learn, I'd appreciate facts and even the preferences/opinions of learned professionals.

Comment: If you're building an API use JSON otherwise use whatever you're more comfortable with, performance wise both are about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, either way would work. However, the standard would be to use individual fields. A major con to using a JSON object would be using it with frameworks. It could cause you some difficulties and may require some additional processing on your part. To keep everything clean and simple I would suggest using fields. It's up to you and what you feel would work best. Hope that helps!